# Use the limit definition to explain why finitely many values of $n$ don't matter

Tags: limits

The problem is the following:
Suppose that $(s_n)$ and $(t_n)$ are sequences so that $s_n = t_n$ except for finitely many values of $n$. Using the definition of limit, explain why if $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} s_n = s$, then also $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} t_n = s$.
I get the general idea, and I can explain it but writing it is completely beyond me

Comment: If two sequences $s_n,t_n$ satisfy $\lim_{n \to \infty} (s_n - t_n) = 0$, then the limits of $s_n$ and $t_n$ must exist and be equal if any one exists, by the addition rule of limits. In your case, $s_n-t_n$ is eventually zero, so converges to zero. But your statement is a specific case of what I have written.

Answer (score 0):

Let $M\in\mathbb N$ be such that $n\geqslant M\implies s_n=t_n$.

Take $\varepsilon>0$. You know that there is a $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $n\geqslant N\implies\lvert s_n-s\rvert<\varepsilon$. Then$$n\geqslant\max\{M,N\}\implies\lvert t_n-s\rvert<\varepsilon,$$since $n\geqslant\max\{M,N\}\implies t_n=s_n$ and $\lvert s_n-s\rvert<\varepsilon$.

Comment: So M here is a number after which the two sequences are equal?

Comment: Yes, that's it.